# I want to get highest value after getting the values in array from firebase. How can I get?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I tried below code to get values in array from firebase but I could not get it whats the wrong in below code

```
dispatch(AssignRequest());
        return DB.database.ref('/BidData').on('value', snap => {
            // console.log('biddDataaa', snap.val())
            // var Amount  =  snap.val().amount;

            const todo = [];
            snap.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                var innerTodo = childSnapshot.val();
                // console.log('AAAAAmmmmmmont', innerTodo.amount)
                var price =parseInt( innerTodo.amount);
                console.log('pricee-------------',price)
                var maxAmount = 0;
                for(var i = 0;i< price.lenght;i++ ){
                    if(price[i].lenght> maxAmount){
                        maxAmount = price[i].lenght
                        console.log('mahhhhhhhh',maxAmount)
                    }
                } 
return maxAmount;
```

Comment: You should do if(price[i]> maxAmount) { and you have a typo with lenght instead of length. Your javascript console should show you the second error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the *val()* on the snapshot before looping

Comment: He calls `childSnapshot.val()` inside the loop. That is preferred in general (though it makes no difference in this case), since it ensures he loops over the child nodes in order.